# How to find cores and logical processors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can see 4 processors when i right click on SQL server instance -> properties->General->Processors,

does it mean is the server had 2 core processor or 4 core processor? what is CORE? where do i check how many cores sql server has?

Very much appreciate your replies

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68383/how-can-i-tell-how-many-cores-sql-server-is-actually-using).

It quotes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143760(v=sql.105)

> SQL Server supports the specified number of processor sockets
>   multiplied by the number of logical CPUs in each socket. For example,
>   the following is considered a single processor for purposes of this
>   table: A single-core, hyper-threaded processor with 2 logical CPUs per
>   socket. A dual-core processor with 2 logical CPUs. A quad-core
>   processor with 4 logical CPUs. SQL Server is licensed per processor
>   socket, and not per logical CPU basis.